# How to avoid error because of relationship break in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, relation

We have Project which expands too much . Now problem is there are long relationship between tables for example `$product->purchaseorder->purchaseorderproduct->saleorders` if any one of the is delete or not found system gives error. Is there any way to avoid these errors?

Comment: First of all if product has saleorders, I would create a relationship between the two. If not, why don't you check if the relationship exists? If you want, you can use the [`optional helper`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-optional). This could solve some / most of your problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really does depend on where you want the validation to lie, before the frontend would be like this:

```
// Backend
// This makes sure all the nested relationships exist on the given model
Product::has('purchaseorder.purchaseorderproduct.saleorders')->get();
```

However, if your validation lies within the frontend then you should use this syntax using blade perhaps?

```
{{-- Frontend --}}
{{-- This makes sure no 500 errors occur within the frontend  --}}
@if(! is_null($product->purchaseorder->purchaseorderproduct->saleorders))
   {{-- Do something here if all passes --}}
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
data_get($product, 'purchaseorder.purchaseorderproduct.saleorders');
```

Comment: how we can use it ? can you please explain it?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-data-get

data_get($target, $key, $default = null)

Get an item from an array or object using "dot" notation